# Computer management(Device manager) is not launching by right click on My Computer?

Tags: windows-7, device-manager, file-types

I face this problem very commonly whenever I install the fresh Windows 7 it works only for a week or may be twice but after that it gives me error and all the time I've to run it through the run command.

[image]

This [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) tells me to store default extension but I don't know which should I've to run to fix it.

Comment: You want the MSC REG file on that page.

Comment: The `compmgmtlauncher.exe` is giving the same error while I'm trying to access it directly from the path.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [MSC REG file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/168993d1312707007-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_msc.reg) on [that page](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html).

You may also want to [view what association](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) is set for MSC files to figure out why it is being changed. Check what program is associated with it and maybe you can set that program to stop taking the filetype. (For example, whenever I use the `associate` command of XMPlay, I have to make sure to un-check `.MSC` because while there may be some music files with that extension, I only ever use that extension for *Mirosoft Common Consoles*.)

---

A diagnostic step you can try is to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Run the program, then stop the capture with Ctrl+E (if it’s not already stopped). Press Ctrl+L and add the following two capture filters:

[image: ProcMon filters for .MSC and mscfile]

Next, select only the Registry class filter as shown:

[image: ProcMon class filters for Registry]

Now, clear any capture data with Ctrl+X, then start the capture with Ctrl+E. Finally, *Run* `devmgmt.msc`.

Wait for the Device Manager to start, then switch back to Process Monitor and stop the capture again.

Now either get a complete screenshot of the output (like below, expect full), or even better, File->Save the capture dump to a PML file. That way I can check to see what the heck is being accessed and where it is failing. You can upload to any [file-dump site](http://www.google.com/search?q=upload%20file).

[image: Sample ProcMon capture from running devmgmt.msc]

Comment: I tried with MSC Reg file but still the same error is occurring.

Comment: Did you reboot? Did you check the current filetype-association?

Comment: No I didn't rebooted the system as generally I don't restart after adding registries. I'll respond you after restart.

Comment: Nopes it doesn't fixed it. Now how can I check association for msc.

Comment: .Msc is associated with Microsoft Management Console.

Comment: Use the Nirsoft program I liked to in the answer. Run it and scroll down to the `.MSC` row. Look at the list in the bottom pane and check if the `Open` item has a command-line of `%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe`. Also, try manually opening it by running `mmc.exe %systemroot%\system32\devmgmt.msc` What happens then? Does it open?

Comment: Through run cmd it runs properly. And Nirsoft shows the same as I got from default program. And `open` has this command `%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe "%1" %*`.

Comment: Strange; usually the `Open` command is automatically used when no default is selected. Try manually setting the default to `Open` by double-clicking the `Open` row in the bottom pane and selecting the `Default Action` checkbox (and clicking OK).

Comment: NO still not working. BY the way nice program + 1 for this.

Comment: Hmm, *really* strange. You have the correct handler installed and selected, so it *should* be using it. And clearly there is no problem with actually running the MMC snap-in. I’m currently in XP, so I’ll try to do some tests when I reboot into 7…

Comment: @Synetechinc. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1074/discussion-between-avirk-and-synetech-inc)

Comment: It could be that the computer-management class has become corrupted. Try re-registering it as so: `regsvr32 /s mycomput.dll`

Comment: Did the same but still not any changes. I'll wait for next reboot and then try to it. Should I download another copy of `comput.dll` from somewhere if available?

Comment: Do other MMC snapins (e.g., `services.msc`, `diskmgmt.msc`) work?

Comment: Yes, however `compmgmt.msc` running through run command clearly.